# Turn off zipping in phpexcel?

Tags: php, zip, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel to create a xls file. I want to turn off zipping though. I don't have the php extension for zipping and I'd rather just send people the xlsx file unzipped. Is there a setting that would allow me to turn it off?

Comment: First question: Are you creating an xls file or an xlsx file? Second question: What do you mean by "turning off zipping"? An xls file isn't zipped in any way, and an xlsx file is (by definition) a zipped collection of xml files: if not zipped, it isn't an xlsx file. If you don't have the php_zip extension enabled, then either you can't create .xlsx files, or you use PCLZip instead, which can be configured (for writing, at least) using PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP).

Comment: Perhaps it's an xls file. I'm using phpexcel excel2007 class.

Comment: Excel2007 is for writing .xlsx files, Excel5 is for writing .xls files. You don't need php_zip to write Excel2007 __if__ you use PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. "zipping" in xlsx is not meant to provide compression and decrease file size, xlsx file is in fact zip file with proper directory structure inside and many xml files.

Comment: I was looking at the code for creating an excel2007 spreadsheet. From what I was seeing, it looked as if it was going to create a spreadsheet and then put that within a .zip file. Perhaps though zipping is required simply to make an xlsx?

Comment: An XLSX file is zipped by definition. The archive contains a number of different files internally, all of which are part of the spreadsheet, and none of which Excel will recognize outside the archive.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the help guys. I'll try to figure out another way around my problem. I found out my other server has ZipArchive